# integral over limsup of numerical function

Tags: measure-theory

I have to show that inquality but I donot know how?
let $(\Omega,A,\mu)$ be a measure space and let $f_n$ ,n$\in$ N be nonnegative measurable numerical function on $\Omega$ ,show that   $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \int_\Omega f_n d\mu<\int_\Omega (\limsup f_n)_{n\to\infty} d\mu$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n = n \cdot 1_{[0,{1 \over n}]}$ on $[0,1]$ with the uniform measure.

Then $\int f_n = 1$ for all $n$. However, $\limsup f_n(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,1]$ and so $\int \limsup f_n = 0$.

**Addendum**:
If there is some integrable $g$ such that $f_n(x) \le g(x)$ for ae. $x$ then the result is true.
This follows by applying Fatou's lemma to $g-f_n \ge 0$, and noting that
$\liminf_n (g-f_n) = g -\limsup f_n$, and
$\liminf_n \int (g-f_n) = 
\int g -\limsup_n \int f_n$.

The above counterexample fails because if $g \ge f_n$ for all $n$, then $g$ cannot be integrable.

Comment: yes this is right but I mean how I kan prove it in general ,without example!!

Comment: It is not true, this is a counterexample.